# Does any lib or tools can calculate the cpu usage and some other parameters for different process in C/C++ under Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, cpu-usage

Now my project is based on multi-process and I try to calculate the some parameters of each process, such as cpu usage, io usage. I use C++ and my project runs under Linux. Does any lib or open source project can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel exposes such parameters thru the `/proc` filesystem, see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more.

Files inside `/proc/` are usually textual files and should be read sequentially (they are generated on the fly like pipes; often [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) on them gives a 0 meaningless size). Reading these pseudo-files does not involve any disk I/O so is really quick.

Try for instance the following commands:

```
 cat /proc/self/maps
 cat /proc/$$/status
```

For instance, to get the program size `progsize` (actually process size) of a process of pid `pid` you might do:

```
 long progsize= -1;
 pid_t pid = something();
 char path[32];
 snprintf (path, sizeof(path), "/proc/%d/statm", (int) pid);
 FILE *fil = fopen(path, "r");
 if (fil) {
   fscanf(fil, "%ld", &progsize);
   fclose(fil);
 } else { perror(path); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

You might want to parse `/proc/1234/stat` for timing (and resident set size, i.e. used RAM, etc etc...) information of pid 1234.

For your finished child processes, use also [wait4(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html) which fills a `struct rusage` about the child process, see also [getrusage(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html)

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by `progsize`. You can get RSS sizes easily with `getrusage` though without having to open files and parse text. However, generally `/proc` exposes more than one could get with function calls.

Comment: It (my `progsize`) is documented in [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), and `getrusage` might not tell enough about IO usage...

Comment: That man page says _/proc/[pid]/statm size (1) total program size (same as VmSize in /proc/[pid]/status)_, i.e. it is just the size of the virtual address space, not how much physical memory it actually uses.

Comment: Yes. But I guess that virtual memory, not physical memory, matters more. However, OP could parse `/proc/$PID/stat` and its 24th `rss` field to get the *Resident Set Size: number of pages the
                          process has in real memory*

Comment: It seems can get the running process, but the finished process cannot be recorded. Do you have any methods?

Comment: Edited answer to mention `wait4`